# Kafka Blue/Green deployment, how to seamlessly migrate consumers

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, blue-green-deployment

We are currently experiencing challenges while implementing the Blue/Green deployment strategy for our services.

Our service architecture consists of several micro-services and a Kafka queue, with external producers and consumers. The decision to adopt the Blue/Green strategy was made in order to seamlessly handle any breaking changes that may occur. However, we have encountered an obstacle.

The issue arises when utilizing the traffic manager to connect to our Kafka service. Currently, consumers are successfully connecting to Kafka using the traffic manager URL. When we attempt to switch to the new cluster, we simply need to modify the traffic manager settings, resulting in an updated URL for the Kafka server.

Unfortunately, despite this URL update, the consumers continue to consume data from the old cluster. We are seeking guidance on how to enforce the consumers to begin consuming data from the new cluster.

Are there any settings that can help us here?

TIA.

Comment: Are consumers also configured using traffic manager? Consumers and producers have config to which cluster they have to connect. Did you modify the consumer config?

Comment: @Steephen yeah the consumers and produers are also connecting via the traffic manager url and are not directly connecting to the kafka-cluster.

I understand that once the connection is opened the consumer and producer continue using that connection to read data, but was wondering if we can force refresh the connection somehow so that they can connect to the new cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what "traffic manager" means here since that's not part of the Kafka protocol, but

1. The brokers return `advertised.listeners` to clients, despite you telling them to use "traffic manager" to bootstrap. This means clients will have direct knowledge of the (original) brokers after they are connected.
2. Clients have a 5 minute window for `metadata.max.age.ms` to find new brokers and partitions, however this assumes the same cluster.

Sounds like you need to stop/close the consumers, and reconnect through your "traffic manager" so that a new set of bootstrap servers would be returned.

In general, I've found Kafka consumers don't work in a blue-green environment because of shared consumer groups and both sides will be consuming data, potentially with different processing logic.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, the consumers that we have are external. And hence we can't close and restart them. 

Hence I am looking for options to refresh the DNS for the running consumers. I am setting the 'metadata.max.age.ms' values, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. I've set that value to 10 ms.

Comment: In Java, there is also a DNS cache, and otherwise, the brokers will always resolve to IP addresses. I dont know of any way to re-do a DNS request without manually reconnecting the clients

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't do this way. Let me try to explain; you are trying to switch the network traffic and hope everything will work smoothly.

I am totally ignorant of TrafficManager, and I am considering it as a black box you are relying to switch the traffic and proxying the network.

Producer uses the IP address provided by your TrafficManager and creating the connection to brokers. And when it produces a record to Kafka; along with every record, Kafka add additional metadata and one of them is offset. When consumer consume data from kafka, consumer will use this offset and map it against consumer group and create a new record in a system topic called __consumer_offset. When you switch network traffic you are leaving behind quite a lot of metadata in your old cluster and your consumers will become incapable to continue to work as before.